# Сменить заголовки ответа от сервера

Tags: config, сервер

[image]

Возможно ли сменить Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) на qweqwe, например, где-то в конфигурациях?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServerName в httpd.conf не поможет?

Comment: @Get, ServerName содержит адрес сайта :(

http://c2n.me/38xPHYU.png

Comment: Здесь с настройками придумывают http://www.howtoforge.com/changing-apache-server-name-to-whatever-you-want-with-mod_security-on-debian-6

Здесь в исходниках меняют http://www.geeksww.com/tutorials/servers/apache_web_http_server/tips_and_tricks/giving_apache_web_server_a_different_name_by_changing_source_code_before_installation.php

А здесь что-то непонятное делать предлагают, но, видимо, работает.
http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/4179400.htm